# Filtering Django admin site by user group

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i want to filter the objects displayed on the admin site by using Django user groups. Each user is assigned to one or more user groups which represent different categories of articles. Each article falls into one or more categories (the names of the user groups and categories are identical). On the admin site for the Article object, users shall only see articles from categories of which they are a group member. I found a basic approach by overriding **get_queryset** within ModelAdmin and retrieving a list with the user's group names. But how can i reference the **ArticleCategory** model within **ArticleAdmin** to do the comparison with the group names?

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)

class ArticleCategory(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    def __str__ (self):
        return(str(self.article) + " " + str(self.category))
    def natural_key(self):
        return ({'category': self.category})
```

admin.py

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Article

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            queryset = Article.objects.all()
        else:
            try:
                l = request.user.groups.values_list('name',flat = True)
                l_as_list = list(l)
                queryset = Article.objects.filter(??? in l_as_list)
            except:
                queryset = Article.objects.none()
        return queryset

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

The following line didn't work:

```
queryset = Article.objects.filter(articlecategory__category.name in l_as_list)
```

Comment: users shall only see articles from categories of which they are a member

Can you provide the model where the user is member of articles?

Comment: The user is only a member of categories, not of specific articles. I'm using Django's bult-in Group model for managing those memberships.